# Compiling Speex successful on iPhone simulator but failed on iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, speex

I tried to compile Speex library on iOS following [this tutorial](http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/compile-speex-for-iphone/) and succeeded to do it in the iPhone simulator, but the build fails on a real device. I get some errors like `"Use of undeclared identifier __m128"`, which looks like there are some problems with compiling C/C++ sources on a real device. I would be very thankful if someone could propose a solution.

Here is also my source code: https://github.com/artem888/SpeexTest

Artem

Comment: This guy has a nice configured project for this: https://github.com/kronik/ZhiShi/tree/master/src/iPhone-Speech-To-Text

Comment: your source code no nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the problem:

Needed to uncomment `#define _USE_SSE` in **config.h** , after that lib compiles and runs successfully.

Many thanks to Cliff's tutorials:

1. http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/compile-speex-for-iphone/
2. http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/speex-on-iphone-explained/
3. http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/speex-on-iphone-explained-part-ii/

Answer (score 1):

You can find a precompiled Speex library for iOS on github here: http://bit.ly/151x6E2

You'll also need the Ogg library. You can find that here: http://bit.ly/P40pxG

If you don't like using precompiled libraries, each of the above repositories now contain scripts to allow you to reproduce the builds. These rely on some additional utility scripts: http://bit.ly/19cYCQj

I have just updated the repository for arm64!